# SpringBoot - How to pass exceptions from other classes

Tags: java, spring, exception

i have created a relativ complex SpringBoot-Application for REST-Calls for executing different operations in Tds/OpenLdap, etc..
Now i want to improve my application regarding the exception handling. But here i have a little problem or understanding problem.
For example, i have my outer class which can remove a user from group:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/usergroups", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void removeUserFromGroup(@RequestBody final LdapGroup LdapGroup) throws Exception{
// check input data
        if(LdapGroup.getUserid().isEmpty()){
            logger.warning("The Request-Parameter 'userid:' is missing or empty");
            throw new MissingParameter("The Request-Parameter 'userid:' is missing or empty");
            }
// some other checks ......

            if (ldapAdapter.doesUserExist(LdapGroup.getUserid()) == false) {
                logger.warning("Account "+ldapUserGroup.getUserid()+" not exists");
                throw new UserAccountDoesNotExistException("Account does not exist");
            }
            boolean isAssigned = ldapAdapter.isUserAssignedToGroup( LdapGroup.getUserid(), LdapGroup.getGroupid(), LdapGroup.getGroupid());
            if (isAssigned == false){
                logger.warning("User "+LdapGroup.getUserid()+" is not in the group: "+LdapGroup.getGroupid()+ ","+LdapGroup.getGroupOU());
            }
            else{
                ldapAdapter.removeUserFromGroupWithOu( LdapGroup.getUserid(), LdapGroup.getGroupid(), LdapGroup.getGroupOU());  
            }
```

Ok! Because i want to handle different Directories i have an adapter that i can manage them with one SpringApplication. One Class is for the OpenLdap, the method for removing a user from group is like that:

```
@Override
public void removeUserfromGroup(String groupDN, String userDN) throws LdapException {       
    try {           
        ArrayList<ModificationItem> items = new ArrayList<ModificationItem>();
        Attribute userAttribute = new BasicAttribute("uniqueMember", userDN);
        items.add(new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, userAttribute));
        doModify(groupDN, items.toArray(new ModificationItem[items.size()]), false); 
        logger.info("User '" + userDN + "' removed from '" + groupDN + "'");
    } catch (LdapException e) {
        throw e;            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new LdapException(UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION, e);
    }
}
```

The Problem is now, if i fire a Rest-Call to my SpringApplication, i get a Code 500: Internal Server Error without a message. So nobody knows what kind of error it is. In my console i get the LdapException like "[LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]". And this is the relevant information.
How can i pass this Ldap-Exception to my SpringApplication. The best case would be that i only pass the message, because i have defined different Exceptions.classes for the SpringApplication. And these Exception classes inherit from "Exception"

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [@RestControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html).

Create a new class annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice` something like below. This class will intercept the exception(s) being raised from controllers and wrap them with custom response. This custom response body will carry the error message and optionally the custom HTTP response code (*e.g. 400 whenn `SomeExpection` is raised - as shown in `handleSomeException` method below*)

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExampleRestControllerAdvice {

@ExceptionHandler(value = SomeException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleSomeException(SomeException e) {

    ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse();
    response.setErrorMsg(e.getErrorMsg());
    response.setErrorCode(e.getErrorCode().getCode());

    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(Exception e) {

    ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse();
    response.setErrorMsg("Server error");
    response.setErrorCode("ERR007");

    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(response,
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}

}
```

As per need more methods with `@ExceptionHandler` can be added for every type of exception thrown.

You can have `ErrorResponse` class defined something like below

```
public class ErrorResponse {

private String errorCode;
private String errorMsg;

public String getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}

public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}

public String getErrorMsg() {
    return errorMsg;
}

public void setErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {
    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
}

}
```

Let know in comments if you need further info / clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am just trying to implement your idea. So i understood, that my SpringApplication creates with the "@RestControllerAdvice"-Annotation a custom ExceptionResponse. I understand the idea behind that.
But not exactly in my case. Where is the linking from my OpenLdapController and my Spring-Rest-Application?
Because for example the error response from the ldap "[LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]" is not a generated error by me. I need to intercept this error from the other class.

Comment: What I understand from question is that exception raised should be intercepted by Spring application i.e. controller - which is what the class annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice` will do. Could you please update the question with more details (*as in project structure, control flow etc.*) in case my I understanding is not correct, so that I can help better.

Comment: So, i think i am finish now and have everything what i wanted to do with your suggested construct. Thank you very much!
I couldn't intercept the exception from ldap ([LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]), but my own exceptions from the Controller before. That's enough for the first time.